# Mobile game framework for non-game programmer

Tags: android, ios, mobile, frameworks, game-engine

I'm a 15-year-old programmer, and I have been programming for a few years, but I've never done any serious game development. I've built a Windows utility (with C++), and I have an Android (Java) and iOS (Objective-C) app in the Google Play Store / iOS App Store.

Now I want to create a mobile game for Android and iOS. As I said, I've never developed a game. What would be a good starting point for me? What framework should I use?

Thank you in advance.

*Update*: I want a cross-platform framework that will work on both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are looking to develop a game for both ios & android with native sdks, you should choose cocos2d - it is opengl based game engine which is available as opensource (free).

you can found it for both the platforms iOS :- http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/
android :- http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android-1/ 
best of luck!!

Answer (score 3):

If you are from a non-programming background, here are a few frameworks that you should try out:

GameSalad
http://gamesalad.com

GameMaker
http://www.yoyogames.com/gamemaker

StencylWorks
http://www.stencyl.com/stencyl/overview/

Construct 2
http://www.scirra.com/

Answer (score 1):

check below link

http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Check out AndEngine, https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Hardik about the Libgdx game framework for Android development. It's a good game development framework. You program in one place and it creates what you need for the game to be on Android and the Web.